# What is the difference between Entity.GetAttributeValue<T>(name) and Entity[name] in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: entity-framework, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

When coding against the CRM SDK using late binding what is the difference between accessing attributes using the GetAttributeValue method and accessing the attributes directly on the Entity object?

I am still very new to .NET and c# so if it is a simple language/platform understanding issue then apologies but maybe that's why I can't find much on the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`entity["myattributename"]` will throw an exception if you attempt to access an attribute that is not in the attribute collection of the entity.  It will also return it as an object.

`entity.GetAttributeValue<T>` will return the default value of the type if not found, and will not throw an exception if it isn't in the attributes collection of the entity.

Answer (score 0):

The `entity.GetAttributeValue<T>` will return an IEnumerable object which can be used in LINQ expressions. This may greatly speed-up development time and reduce lines of code logic.  Based on Daryl's response (good explaination [here](http://crmentropy.blogspot.com/2013/08/entitygetattributevalue-explained.html): ).

Comment: Good Link for a more in depth version of my answer, but GetAttributeValue<T> returns a object of type T, not necessarily an IEnumerable.

Comment: Thanks for this blog link, that helped for depth.